# How would you translate this Pine Script nested loop into Python?

Tags: python, pine-script

I'm new to Pine Script and I've been struggling to understand the logic behind the if/else Pine Script's operators. I can understand all the simple examples that I could find online, but when it comes to the particular code I want to translate into Python, it becomes more difficult. Here is the nested loop I'm struggling to understand:

```
hi:=hi[1]?high[1]>=stop[1]?false:true:low[1]<=stop[1]?true:false
    stop:=hi?max1:min1
    stop:=hi?hi[1]==false?stop:stop>stop[1]?stop[1]:stop:hi[1]?stop:stop<stop[1]?stop[1]:stop
```

As I've mentioned before my goal is to translate this snippet of code into Python. Thank you guys for help!

P.S. this is Pine Script v4

Comment: You should try expanding the answer so that the ?: are on different lines -- that will give you a better idea. a ? b : c means 'if a is true, then return b, else return c'

Answer (score 0):

You can convert any [ternary](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#op_%7Bquestion%7D%7Bcolon%7D) (`?:`) construction to an `if-then-else` on [this website](https://converter.website-dev.eu/)
The `[1]` does not denote an array, but is a [history referencing operator](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Operators.html#history-reference-operator).
With that, you can access values on previous bars.

**First example**

```
hi:=hi[1]?high[1]>=stop[1]?false:true:low[1]<=stop[1]?true:false
```

becomes

```
hi :=
if (hi[1]) {
    if (high[1] >=stop[1]) {
        false
    } else {
        true
    }
} else {
    if (low[1] <=stop[1]) {
        true
    } else {
        false
    }
}
```

**Second example**

```
stop:=hi?max1:min1
```

becomes

```
stop:=
if (hi) {
    max1
} else {
    min1
}
```

**Third example**

```
stop:=hi?hi[1]==false?stop:stop>stop[1]?stop[1]:stop:hi[1]?stop:stop<stop[1]?stop[1]:stop
```

becomes

```
stop := 
if (hi) {
    if (hi[1]==false) {
        stop
    } else {
        if (stop>stop[1]) {
            stop[1]
        } else {
            stop
        }
    }
} else {
    if (hi[1]) {
        stop
    } else {
        if (stop<stop[1]) {
            stop[1]
        } else {
            stop
        }
    }
}
```